# Maven framework compatibility Issue's, Unable to run the scripts in chrome.

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, testng

Maven framework compatibility Issue's, Unable to run the scripts in chrome.

Hi All,

I am not able to run my scripts in other browser other than firefox 46.0. 
I am working on an existing Framework of Maven, scripting platform Selenium webdriver 2017.

Please do let me know any further info about framework is required.

Kindly refer screenshot for reference. [image: Framework]

Comment: Need an urgent help & suggestions.

Comment: You are not working on Maven you are working on a Software library which is Selenium...where your issue is related to..

Comment: Thanks a ton, for an update. I am new to automation.

Answer (score 1):

compatibility issues are generally due to version mismatches. Make sure that the selenium artefact version is compatible with the chrome browser(installed on your PC) version.